# A line chart with a data table docked under the x-axis

Tags: pentaho, dashboard, dashboard-designer

How can I make the A line chart with a data table docked under the x-axis in dashboard like this.

http://www.advsofteng.com/gallery_line.html

The Chart Name is Product Line Global Revenue

Comment: this question is incomplete describe more what you want to do achieve?

Comment: I want to make a dashboard linechart in pentaho, the linechart must have records table under linechart which likes the Product Line Global Revenue chart on hyperlink above

Answer (score 0):

Are you using dashboard designer in the EE version, or CE?  i.e. CDE?

Should be quite simple in CDE. Just create a datasource, then create a layout with a couple of panels. Then add a table component for the table, and a chart component for the line chart.

Same approach in reporting - there is no individual component which allows you to do both at once, so just use the same dataset and create a chart, then create a table.

If you're not yet using CDE / Ctools, then i recommend you take a look, install via marketplace or via ctools-installer.sh

Comment: I use CDE to create dashboard, and I used to design as you said,I want to ask the line chart component in CDE has supported as my question ?

Comment: Dear Mr Codek,I am new in BI platform, I hope I can study more from you, so Would I add your Skype ? my Skype id is sacpv04, thank you very much

Comment: Sorry no; I do not offer free private support!  It is much better to use public spaces so others can benefit.  Community support for CDE is very good, although asking on here is probably not the best place, go through the cheap tutorials from webdetails/ambientbi or checkout the ##pentaho channel on IRC freenode, they are very helpful in there.  There are also good examples you can copy and edit.